# expressjs not throwing error on Parse queries (parse-server)

Tags: express, parse-server

I have a parse-server setup on expressjs like [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example).

But sometimes it's not showing errors inside Parse functions. Example:

```
// Parse Server is setup
// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var pageQuery = new Parse.Query('Page');
  pageQuery.get('id').then(function(page) {
    someObject.undefinedProp = false;
    res.send(page);
  }, function(error) {
    res.send(error);
  });
});
```

No errors displayed, but with this code:

```
// Parse Server is setup
// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  someObject.undefinedProp = false;
  res.send('ok');
});
```

I have this error displayed:

```
ReferenceError: someObject is not defined
```

(For this example I have the exact same configuration as the [Parse Server Example](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example))

I just want to have the errors displayed inside my Parse functions.

Any ideas?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is actually an issue caused by Promises.

When you call `pageQuery.get('id')`, the `get` method returns a Promise instance. The `then` method of the Promise is how you set up your callback that will fire on the successful completion of the `get` operation.

In order to get a reference to the error that should occur when you attempt to reference `someObject.undefinedProp`, you'll also need to set up an error handler on that Promise object by calling its `catch` method.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var pageQuery = new Parse.Query('Page');

  pageQuery.get('id').then(function(page) {
    someObject.undefinedProp = false; 
    // the error thrown here will be caught by the Promise object
    // and will only be available to the catch callback below
    res.send(page);

  }, function(error) {
    // this second callback passed to the then method will only
    // catch errors thrown by the pageQuery.get method, not errors
    // generated by the preceding callback
    res.send(error);

  }).catch(function (err) {
    // the err in this scope will be your ReferenceError
    doSomething(err);
  });
});
```

Here, check out the following article and scroll down to the section heading "Advanced mistake #2: catch() isn't exactly like then(null, ...)".

https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html